# how to search through json object that contains mutliple json objects and update particular value of sub object in java?

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have json as follows

```
{
   "students":[{
  "name":"abc",
"id":"1",
"age":"34",
"hobby":"sports"
     },{
  "name":"pqr",
"id":"2",
"age":"25",
"hobby":"dance"
     },
    ]
}
```

and I want to update the value of {
      "name":"pqr",
    "id":"2",
    "age":"25",
    "hobby":"dance"
         }, this  hobby to "reading"
can someone help me? I'm new to json objects

Comment: Please try to be a little clearer with your question, also please include your attempt at this.

Comment: I guess you should parse that JSON into some object structure; update the object; and transform it back into JSON. A lot of steps; so where exactly in that process are you stuck? Hint: put up a [mcve] to avoid the impression that you expect us to do all the work for you.

Comment: I have updated my question can you please chek it again ? @NickDelaney

Answer (score 0):

Convert your json string to a java object and update the value using setter method

Go through this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/.

Answer (score 0):

first step you have to make a student class

```
public class Student{
private String name;
private String id;
private String age;
private String hobby;
}
```

second step use GSON lib with arrayList of Student like this

```
ArrayList<Student>arrayList=new Gson().fromJson(MyJsonStructure,Student.class);
```